# Raw loader vs url loader in webpack

Tags: webpack, urlloader, raw-loader

Anyone know the difference between the raw loader vs url loader in webpack? does the url loader do the same as raw, except falls back to file-loader at a certain file size?

Comment: raw loader loads the text in the file where it is required, where as url-loader fixed the url paths in the file that it loads. they are way different

Comment: can you explain more fully with example, and put in answer? @entre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## url-loader

Loads the images you load via `url(./some-asset.jpg)` in your css files, converts them to base64 and places them instead of the url() statement.

## raw-loader

Loads the file as string, it **doesn't** convert the images to base64, and is used more for text or css files.

Comment: Depends on the use case, for example - it's great for loading templates